# How to memoize at class level?

Tags: python-3.x, class, caching, memoization

I have the following `class`, with a cached `property` as so:

```
class Object:

  def __init__(self, var):
    self._var = var

  @property
  @lru_cache()
  def some_property(self):
     print("i did some calculation")
     return self._var + 3

>> obj = Object(3)
>> obj.some_property
i did some calculation
6
```

How can I make it so that whenever I make a new `Object`, with the same `var`, it will not recalculate, but rather `memoize` the result fat `class level` and not recalculate `somme_property`.

In other words I would need it to behave as so:

```
>> new_obj = Object(3)
>> new_obj.some_property
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer but a suggestion. You could just create a function inside `Object` which will hold the variable.
Something like this:

```
def memorize(x):
  self.MemorizedValue = x
```

Then you can pass the value through `Object.memorize(3)`.